# How to get text input from UITextField?

Tags: swift, text, uitextfield, textfield

How to get text input from UITextField ?

I tried this:

```
@IBAction func input(_ sender: UITextField) {  
    label.text = textfield.text
}
```

But the label doesn't get the textfield input.
Which Code should I use?

Comment: "Doesn't work" is the least useful way to describe an issue. Please [edit] your question to clearly specify what issue you are having. In what way exactly doesn't that code work?

Comment: Is your `input` method being called? What event is it connected to?

Comment: Thanks. But I just want to know how I get the users input from the textfield.

Comment: The code you posted will do just that. But only if your `input` method is actually being called. And assuming the label is actually on screen.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Main.storyboard. This is where you can see a preview of your App including your TextField.
2. Open the Assistant Editor. You can do so by clicking the two circles in the top right corner. Now you should have a split screen View of Main.storyboard and ViewController.swift.
3. Press the ctrl key and click the textfield. Now drag it in view controller.swift right below the "{" after the view controller statement at the top.
4. Release the key and the mouse. Now you have to select "Outlet" in the appearing and use a name
5. Now You can get the text anywhere in your program by calling the name you selected in step 4 and .text . E.g. name.text

**What you did is create an Action. So your action function gets called whenever someone e.g. clicks the textfield. If you want to get the text of it then just use sender.text inside the action function.
I hope this helps.**

Comment: Thank you. I tried out sender. It shows no mistakes. But I can't exit the textfield while running on iOS.

Comment: @Hello.12397 Glad it worked. Accept my answer if it helped.

Answer (score -1):

Try to add @IBOutlet instead of @IBAction

For ex:
@IBOutlet weak var yourTextField: UITextField!

and then you can print it out:
print(yourTextField!)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).